# How Can I Drag My Annotation On MKmap View Like Google Pin Drop And Draging:iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, mkmapview

I need some help. How can i drag annotation (map pin) from one point to another in MKMapview.
Adding process is all good after pin drop-down on the map and i want to drag that pin (annotation) and change that place just like Google map.

***Happy Coding***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First allow pin to drag

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView: (MKMapView *) mapView viewForAnnotation: (id) annotation 
{ 
    pin.draggable = YES; 
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
 annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView
didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState
   fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState
{
    if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D droppedAt = annotationView.annotation.coordinate;
        [annotationView.annotation setCoordinate:droppedAt];
         if(DEBUG_MODE){
        NSLog(@"Pin dropped at %f,%f", droppedAt.latitude, droppedAt.longitude);
         }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The process is you need to allow pin to dragable, and you will get that destination's lat long on `didChangeDragState` of `MKMapView`.

Try below code.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"ident"];
    pinView.draggable = YES;
    pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
    return pinView;
}
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
 annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView
didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState
   fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState
{
    if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding)
    {
        droppedAt = annotationView.annotation.coordinate;
        NSLog(@"Pin dropped at %f,%f", droppedAt.latitude, droppedAt.longitude);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To drag an annotation, set the annotation's draggable property to YES.

set the annotation's draggable in the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method.

Use delegate method `didChangeDragState` method to get new coordinates of your annotation.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
        annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView 
        didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState 
        fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState 
{

    if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateStarting) {


    }
    if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding) //Annotation dragging ended
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D droppedCord = annotationView.annotation.coordinate;
        NSLog(@"New position %f,%f", droppedCord.latitude, droppedCord.longitude);
    }
}
```